# Can't redirect to success page in Django + Stripe project

Tags: python, django, django-views, stripe-payments

I'm developing my first test Django Stripe project, but I'm currently stuck at the point because the redirect on success page is not working.

This is my views.py file

```
import stripe
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views import View
from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from .models import Item

stripe.api_key = settings.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY


class ProductLandingPageView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'landing.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        item_id = self.kwargs["id"]
        item = get_object_or_404(Item, id=item_id)
        context['item'] = item
        return context



class CreateCheckoutSessionView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        item_id = self.kwargs["id"]
        DOMAIN: str = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
        item = Item.objects.get(id=item_id)
        session = stripe.checkout.Session.create(
            payment_method_types=['card'],
            line_items=[
                {
                    'price_data': {
                        'currency': 'usd',
                        'unit_amount': item.price * 100,
                        'product_data': {
                            'name': item.name,
                        },
                    },
                    'quantity': 1,
                },
            ],
            payment_intent_data={
                'metadata': {
                    'item_id': item.id,
                },
            },
            mode='payment',
            success_url=DOMAIN + '/success/',
            cancel_url=DOMAIN + '/cancel/',
        )
        return HttpResponse(session.id)


class SuccessView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "success.html"


class CancelView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "cancel.html"
```

And this is my template.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Homepage</title>
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="description">
        <h3>{{ item.name }}</h3>
        <h5>{{ item.display_price }} USD.</h5>
    </div>
    <button id="buy-button" data-item-id="{{ item.id }}">Buy</button>



    <script>
    document.getElementById('buy-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var itemId = this.getAttribute('data-item-id');
  fetch('/buy/' + itemId)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(data) {
      var stripe = Stripe(data.stripe_public_key);
      stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: data.session_id });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Ошибка:', error);
    });
});
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

I'm using env variables for keys so added these lines in settings

```
STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = os.getenv('STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY')
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('STRIPE_SECRET_KEY')
```

And my urls.py is set this way

```
from api.views import CancelView, SuccessView, CreateCheckoutSessionView, ProductLandingPageView
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('item/<int:id>', ProductLandingPageView.as_view(), name='item'),
path('buy/<int:id>', CreateCheckoutSessionView.as_view(), name='buy'),
path('cancel/', CancelView.as_view(), name='cancel'),
path('success/', SuccessView.as_view(), name='success'),]
```

Project structure

[image]

Do you have any suggestions on how to solve the issue?
BTW if you notice any other thing to improve - please feel free to comment it.
I'm very new to stripe service and still learning how it works.

**UPD:**

Problem solved by modifying JS code as follows

```
<script>
    document.getElementById('buy-button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var itemId = this.getAttribute('data-item-id');
  var stripe = Stripe("{{ STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY }}");
  fetch('/buy/' + itemId)
    .then(function(response) {
      return response.json();
    })
    .then(function (session) {
      return stripe.redirectToCheckout({ sessionId: session.id });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.error('Ошибка:', error);
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what is the issue exactly with the redirect? Any error in your backend server or in the browser console?

Comment: No. No error in console. But I just can't inderstand the mecanism of how to be redirected on success template once I push the Buy button

Comment: [02/Jan/2024 13:21:30] "GET /item/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1033
[02/Jan/2024 13:21:36] "GET /buy/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 66

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general you have two options to do the Checkout Session redirect.

Option 1:

- Create a Checkout Session on the backend and send the `checkout.url` to your frontend
- Then on the frontend do the redirection with `window.location.href`

Option 2:

- Have a form on your frontend, something like `<form action="/checkout-session" method="POST"> <button type="submit" /> </form>`
- On the backend, the route `/checkout-session` creates a Checkout Session and return a 303 redirect with the Checkout Session url

Comment: can I use Checkout form with stripe.redirectToCheckout(sessionId=session_id)? Any suggestions on how to modify my code in this case?

Comment: I has been depreciated as mentioned [here](https://stripe.com/docs/js/deprecated/redirect_to_checkout), so I wouldn't recommend it. But technically it should work. please edit your question with more details on the exact issue you are facing if you need more help (any error in your backend server or in the browser console).

Comment: I added apparently all necessary info. Can't really understand why the Buy button still not redirecting me on success page

Comment: Do you see any errors in your backend server or the browser console?

Comment: No. Only messages like 

[02/Jan/2024 13:21:30] "GET /item/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 1033
[02/Jan/2024 13:21:36] "GET /buy/1 HTTP/1.1" 200 66